# I cannot write into specific location in pdf

Tags: eclipse, jdbc, itext

Trying to manipulate pdf with using pdfstamper I don't know what's wrong in the code it doesn't print textfield in output file. Thanks in advance

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("Players.pdf");
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(Result));
AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields(); // using acro fields to fill out the pdf
form.setGenerateAppearances(true);
rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * from Players");
while ( rs.next() ) {
     String Country = null;
     Country = rs.getString("CName");
     System.out.println(Country);
     if (rs != null)
        Country = rs.getString("CName");
     form.setField("Country",Country);
}

stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
stamper.close();
connection.close();
```

Comment: Can any one please point me out where I am going wrong? Since its my code I over look it some times so I am here asking for some help if someone could point me out what's wrong and briefly explain me why does it not print out in output pdf I would greatly appreciate there time and help. Thanks again.

Comment: Possible causes: (1.) The query doesn't return any results. (2.) There is no field named `CName` in the result set. (3.) There is no AcroForm field named `Country` in the PDF. (4.) You aren't using an official iText version. I know that you will claim that all of this isn't true, but that attitude won't help you getting an answer. Sharing the PDF you are trying to fill out would help, because then we can test if your allegation is true or false.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I could not upload the pdf since I don't have enough reputation to post a image. And not to offend you but all the points you have mentioned I have checked thoroughly I get the fetched data on my console but it is failing to write it in the pdf.

Comment: What happens if you replace `while` by `if`? Because right now, you're replacing the value of the field as many times as there are records in the `ResultSet`. In any case: code like this has been working for thousands of developers in thousands of projects. Share the PDF on a fileshare site and add the link to your question.

Comment: Note: checking `if (rs != null)` doesn't make sense. If `rs` were null, a `NullPointerException` would have been thrown at `rs.next()`.